# Use of Microsoft icons / button images in commercial software

Tags: vba, ms-office

Does anyone know the exact legal terms of use of the Microsoft Office 2010 Icons Gallery (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21103), especially for commerical applications (i.e. add-ins for Microsoft Office programs)? I couldn't find it anywhere.

Are these button images only provided for private, non-commercial use (they can be easily added to custom-built ribbons, after all)?

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: This site is for programming questions, not legal advice, or interpreting licensing agreements/EULAs for you. Talk to lawyer. "But some random person on the interwebitubez said it was ok" will just get you laughed out of court if MS decides to haul you in for copyright infringement.

Comment: I'd probably ask Microsoft.

Comment: @Marc B: Yes, I see, I'm off-topic. I will move to Programmers. By the way, your answer was really, really, really incredibly valuable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The icons can only be used by the common Fluent Ribbon definitions in your solutions:

```
Use these icons in your Ribbon solutions by specifying the imageMso value for your controls. 

For example:

   <button id="myButton" label="My save" imageMso="FileSave" /> 

creates a button with the Save icon.
```

So you essentially are **not redistributing** the icons doing so but address the icons already available in the product. So if you for instance build a commercial product using the Fluent Ribbon UI (i.e. RibbonXML) you are allowed to use the identifiers recognized by the Office host applications. Office itself will provide the images that will be displayed in the Ribbon or Context Menus (right click).

Other than that in general you are not allowed to redistribute the Microsoft IP without written confirmation from Microsoft, see the section on Icons:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/legal/intellectualproperty/permissions?30648508-ebb3-4af9-81ba-3cc4c26d67b4=True